# DIfferent homepage on each refresh - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way where i can rotate multiple home pages on each refresh in wordpress.

Basically when i visit the site it needs to show a specific homepage and when i refresh again it needs to show a different home page?

I hope i am making sense.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to change the homepage each time or just the content?

Comment: Hi Lewis, We have almost seven homepage designs with their unique content. The page includes an background image with its content on each side. If it was a image i could use a plugin to make this happen but what i can't figure out is how will i be able to change the content with each image.

Comment: Well in that case you are going to need to have 1 Master homepage template file. You will then put the path to each homepage into an `array`. You then use `rand()` to randomly generate an index number. Then you will get the result src and use a `include` which will import that template.

Comment: Many thanks Lewis. I will try it out

Comment: If you need the code directly, let me know and ill whip something up.

Comment: If that is possible it would be a great help.

Comment: See answer below:

Answer (score 0):

To call to a different homepage template each time use the following code:

```
$homepages =  array('/path/homepage1.php', '/path/homepage2.php', '/path/homepage3.php', '/path/homepage4.php');
$homepageCount = count($homepages);

require_once($homepages[rand($homepageCount)]);
```

This works by putting the path to each homepage into an array, we are then calling to an array index by using a random number which cannot go any higher than the total array index count.