# Change theme/layout on each visit

Tags: html, wordpress, web, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

I was wondering how to make a wordpress website change the visualized theme/layout, every different time a user visit it.

Is there any plugin that comes in help for something like that?

Thank you

I tried googling for plugin and I found a solution here: [DIfferent homepage on each refresh - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671571/different-homepage-on-each-refresh-wordpress) but I'm not very confident with code.

Comment: What do you mean "I'm not very confident with code."?

Comment: That I'm not a developer, so I prefer a plugin or simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a plugin for this, but you can try it to do with cookies.

Comment: Do you mean like resetting cookies for each visit? But how can I make a different homepage rotate every time?

Comment: Lets say you have created a cookie "Site-template" and by default value is 0, when the user view your page, the site-template cookie +1, so now the value of site-template cookie is 1.

So in your template you can check what is the cookie value, and if the value is 0 show this, if value is 1 show another template

Comment: I made progresses, but opened another thread, because there's another problem now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117487/how-do-i-recall-corresponding-css-files-of-different-elementor-pages-to-be-displ