# How do I recall corresponding CSS files of different Elementor pages to be displayed in a random array showing different pages every refresh?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor, chat-gpt-4

I have a Wordpress website, made with Elementor, in which I'd like to show a different homepage at every refresh from the users.

To do that, I created different pages (home1, home2, [...] home9) and set as Homepage in Wordpress, a page called "Random Homepages", in which the template used is a custom template made with this code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Random Homepage
 */

// Define an array of homepage slugs
$homepages = array('home1', 'home2', 'home3', 'home4', 'home5', 'home6', 'home7', 'home8', 'home9');

// Get a random slug from the array
$randomSlug = $homepages[array_rand($homepages)];

// Query the content of the randomly selected homepage
$homepage_query = new WP_Query(array('pagename' => $randomSlug));

// Check if the query has content
if ($homepage_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($homepage_query->have_posts()) :
        $homepage_query->the_post();
        // Display the content of the selected homepage
        the_content();
    endwhile;
else :
    // Handle the case where the page doesn't exist
    echo 'Homepage not found.';
endif;

// Reset post data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

It works, at every refresh of my website ["www.fofain.it"](https://fofain.it) it shows a different homepage (for now I only created home1 and home2 for testing), but the CSS is not loading. How do I recall it in the PHP? I assume the CSS are generated by Elementor itself somewhere in folders of the theme.

Can you help me, please?

I tried asking to ChatGPT, it suggested me to add:

```
 // Get the slug of the randomly selected homepage
    $selected_homepage_slug = $randomSlug;

    // Generate the CSS file name based on the selected homepage slug
    $css_file_name = 'style-' . $selected_homepage_slug . '.css';

    // Get the URL of the CSS file
    $css_file_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/css/' . $css_file_name;

    // Output the CSS file link in the HTML head
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . esc_url($css_file_url) . '">';
```

but  searching for the path of the CSS files to substitute instead of '/path/to/css' I got lost, because there too many different paths for all the CSS files